# Asp.Net 5 - On the fly compilation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I just got an ASP.NET 5 Web API Application running in Visual Studio code by following [this guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/ASPnet5) and I can launch the application by executing the command "dnx . web". How can I make the application build on the fly when I make changes to the source file ?

**Update - This seems to be an open issue.** [Link 1](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/22), [Link 2](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/45)

Comment: What did you try? Did you try modifying the file and then saving it, then refreshing the page?

Comment: I'd think it was that way by default, as that's the default behavior, normally. Did you try it? Did it not work? Add details in an [edit]. Make sure you do a hard refresh in the browser when testing.

Comment: Mason and Will - I changed the action method's (GET Method) return value, saved the file and did a hard refresh.

Comment: @Raathigesh And what happened?

Comment: @mason - The API was returning the previous result. Not the updated result. If I run "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5000" again, it would restart the server and will return the updated results.

Comment: On a previous version of ASP.NET 5, you had a to add a `--watch` argument to get that functionality. Try adding that, then describe the results.

Comment: @mason - I executed "dnx --watch .  Web" and received a message saying "Strated" and my content got served but when I made a change in the source file and saved it, the server just stopped without any message or error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dnx . web --watch` is the command that you are looking for.

However, there is a caveat when you do that from command line: when a file changes, the server is stopped.

When you do the same from VS 2015, VS knows how to restart the server when it stops.

Comment: Is there any way in command line or in VS Code, we can restart the server? Or Do we need to write custom gulp task to achieve this workflow ? Thanks you for taking time to answer!

Answer (score 1):

I noticed I had the same problem, and it seems to work more or less as expected if you run your site without the debugger attached.

I think the debugger is more sensitive to changes in cs files, and does't want them to change while it's trying to trace/step through them.

At first I thought it was related to the CLR type you use to run it, but I can change that and it works as long as youre not debugging.